# Setting up Devise sign up views as modals

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, bootstrap-modal

RAILS Newbie here! I have been trying all the possible help, tutorials there is to override Devise controller in order to show the log in/sign up devise form into a modal (Basically would like to be as close as possible from the AirBnB one).

I've created a new controller: registrations_controller.rb to allow devise the use of js:

```
class  Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
respond_to :js
end
```

updated the route.rb with -> registrations: 'registrations':

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
 devise_for :users,
  controllers: { omniauth_callbacks: 'users/omniauth_callbacks', registrations: ‘registrations’ }

 root to: 'pages#home'
end
```

And finally in devise/registrations file used _new.html.erb

```
<div id=”modal” class=”modal fade”></div>

<div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
 <div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
   <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal">x</button>
   <h2 class="dark">Log in</h2>
 </div>
 <div class="modal-body">
  <%= simple_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
    <%= f.error_notification %>

    <div class="form-inputs">
      <%= f.input :name, required: true, autofocus: true %>
      <%= f.input :email, required: true, autofocus: true %>
      <%= f.select :university, options_for_select(%w[Mcgill Concordia Others]), {:include_blank => "Select your university" } %>
      <%= f.input :password, required: true, hint: ("#{@minimum_password_length} characters minimum" if @minimum_password_length) %>
       <%= f.input :password_confirmation, required: true %>
     </div>

     <div class="form-actions">
       <%= f.button :submit, "Sign up" %>
     </div>
   <% end %>

   <%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

and created new.js.erb to render the new.html.erb partial:

```
$(‘#modal’).html(‘<%= j render(“new”) %>’);
$(‘#modal’).modal();
```

When I try to launch the server it give me this error:

```
 undefined local variable or method `‘registrations’'
```

Can someone explain why? thanks!

Comment: Why do those apostrophes look different on registrations in this line? `controllers: { omniauth_callbacks: 'users/omniauth_callbacks', registrations: ‘registrations’ }`

Answer (score 1):

The non-classical apostrophes were indeed the issue of the error, however my modal was still not functioning. I went with an easier approach by doing this: 
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Display-a-custom-sign_in-form-anywhere-in-your-app

Answer (score 0):

I would say as allways the pc was correct. ;)

In modal view controller you have a Model: "User" this needs a controller for routing "Usercontroller" and this controller needs methods `def index end` this method leads to a view `views/user/index.html.erb`. When you wanna load html content over Ajax or like you do it here, you can simple render a view with `render form| to ./_form.html.erb`

In your case he search a method. When you wanna render over a method search for the error ;)

I hope you understand is, if not just ask ;)

Answer (score 0):

It may be not just non-classical apostrophes in  registrations: `‘registrations’`  (as Brad Axe noticed).

You can try specify that key-value pair as  `registrations: 'users/registrations'` to tell ActionDispatch router to search specifically for **Users::RegistrationsController** in `controllers/users/registrations_controller.rb` (if it is there).

After that you can check routing correctness with `rake routes`.

Also it is useful to trace bug in error's log (below error message) where you can find exact file and line of code where the exception occurs.